# How to resize label proportional to its superview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have a view which contains a label (one line label). The label its centered horizontally in the top part of the view (20 from the top). When this view is resized (for example for iPhone 5 screen) I want my label to resize as well.

The label font has size of 55, when the view is resized the font remains the same and it looks to big.

Currently my constraints are just centered horizontally and 20 from the top.

How can I make my label to resize proportional to its view ?

Comment: Use size classes for that matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you need the font to scale?

You can use Minimum Font Scale beside Autoshrink in the Label's properties.

Just set your label's font to the maximum size you want it and set Minimum Font Scale to the mimimum size you would like that font to be at it's smallest.

For example if you leave it to the default value of 0.5 the font would shrink to half of it's original size.

Then you need to tell your label to stretch proportionally to the view.
Simply add Leading and Trailing constraints to the label and it will scale it's boundaries when the superview resizes.

The font will scale until the text can fill the boundaries of the label using the font size as maximum and Minimum Font Scale as minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way is using [Cartography](https://github.com/robb/Cartography) for auto layout.

```
constrain(labelView, yourSuperView) {
     view, view1 in 

     view.top == view.superView.top
     //...
}
```